# use java class service inside rules

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine

I want to declare service class inside drl file to call the function,I used  the following code  but the then code don't work after declaring RouteService  inside when

RouteService.java

```
public class RouteService {

@Inject
RouteRepository routeRepository;


public void Save(Route route){
    routeRepository.save(route);
}
```

.drl file ruls

```
when
    $todo : Todo(route.getId() == 5202)
    $routeService : RouteService()
then
    Score $score = new Score();
    $score.setRunid(10);
    $score.setDomain("domain");
    $score.setStatus("Active");
    $score.setValue(52);
    $routeService.save($score);
end
```

Can anyone show me how use java class service inside rules in .drl file?

Comment: Class `RouteService` has method `Save`, but you are calling `save`. - You really should be more accurate when saying "code don't work".

Comment: Technically, you are not **declaring** `RouteService` inside the when part of your rule. You are just defining a pattern that will match to any instance of `RouteService` present in your session. Just to clarify, where do you have your class definition? Is it inside the .drl file or in a separate .java file?

Answer (score 0):

1. first import user service class.
2. then set it as a global variable inside the drool file.

import com.intervest.notification.service.RadiusFilterService;
global RadiusFilterService radiusFilterService;

rule "your rule name"

when
$map : Map();
then
Map $originDataMap = (Map) $map.get("originDataMap");
Long $hashValue =   (Long) $originDataMap.get("request")
end

3. then where the rule engine define.

@Autowired
private RouteService routerService;

kieRuntime.setGlobal("RouteService", RouteService);